# give color to specific row of a table acc. to situation

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

I created a table from database column name "Do You have passport" user answers in yes or no I want where user answer is yes that row should be green and row where user answer is no that row is white can any one tell me how can I apply css to this table that works dynamically.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db_dat");
    $havepassport='';
    $sql="SELECT * from upload;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $havepassport.='<table>'.'<tr>'.'<td>';
        $havepassport.=$row['having_passport'];
        $havepassport.='</table>'.'</tr>'.'</td>';
        echo $havepassport;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Apart from the fairly obvious syntax errors, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: I think `$havepassport.='</table>'.'</tr>'.'</td>';` should be `$havepassport.='</td>'.'</tr>'.'</table>';`

Comment: If I tried I will surely post it but I didn't get any logic still

Comment: I want color in where having_passport column ans is yes

Comment: did you try to give css with condition?any code of css?

Comment: I am new to php I don't know how to give css with condition @Leothelion

Comment: Do an if statement on your `$row['having_passport']` . And add a css class to your `<tr>` conditionally with the result of the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Your `while` add new `table` to HTML. So, if you have 100 rows, 100 `table`s will be added to DOM instead of rows.

Use following:

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT * from upload";
$result = $conn -> query($sql);

$havepassport = '<table>';
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $passportClass = $row['having_passport'] == 'Yes' ? 'green' : 'red';
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^ Getting classname depending on the passport value

    $havepassport .= '<tr class='.$passportClass.'>'.
    //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Add Class Here
            '<td>';
                $havepassport. = $row['having_passport'];
    $havepassport .= '</td>'.
        '</tr>';

}
$havepassport .= '</table>';
echo $havepassport;
```

**CSS:**

```
.green {
    background: green;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar very very much

Answer (score 1):

checkout this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/knkp02Ld/1/

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>User Name</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User id</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Whatever</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#mytable td:contains("Yes")').parent().css('background', 'green');
$('#mytable td:contains("No")').parent().css('background', 'red');
```

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

docs: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

**Edit**

Other way you can use .each function like as follows

```
$('#mytable td').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).html();
    if (value == "Yes") {
        $(this).parent().css("background", "red");
    }
});
```

Comment: @rupesharora: did you checked my fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db_dat");
    $havepassport='';
    $sql="SELECT * from upload;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $havepassport.='<table>';

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $passHaveClass = '';
        if($row['having_passport'] =="yes"){
            $passHaveClass = "greenColor";
        }
        $havepassport.='<tr class='.$passHaveClass.'>';
        $havepassport.= '<td>'.$row['having_passport'].'</td>';
        $havepassport.='</tr>;
    }
    $havepassport.='</table>';

    echo $havepassport;
?>
```

the `greenColor` class having bg color is green.